# Dagger 2: Constructor injection not working for android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I have a class and interface. I am trying inject the interface object to my class constructor.
Class and interface are in Kotlin and Dagger module is in java.

Interface

```
interface PurchaseProductRest {
@POST
fun postPurchase(@Url url: String, @HeaderMap authHeaders: Map<String, String>, @Body request: InAppPurchase): Call<String>
}
```

Class

```
class PurchaseProductCall @Inject constructor(val purchaseProductRest: PurchaseProductRest) {
private var authHeaders: HashMap<String, String>
private val TAG = "PurchaseProductCall"

init {
    authHeaders = HashMap()
}

fun ping() {
    Log.e(TAG, "succesful")
}

fun call(url: String, apiKey: String, authToken: String, inAppPurchase: InAppPurchase,
         apiResponse: Action1<String>) {
    authHeaders.clear()
    authHeaders["Authorization"] = authToken
    authHeaders["x-api-key"] = apiKey
    Log.d(TAG, "URL: $url")
    purchaseProductRest.postPurchase(url, authHeaders, inAppPurchase).enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {

            //Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            Observable.just(null as String)
                    .onErrorResumeNext { throwable: Throwable? -> Observable.empty() }
                    .subscribe(apiResponse)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {

            Observable.just<String>(response.body())
                    .onErrorResumeNext { throwable: Throwable? -> Observable.empty() }
                    .subscribe(apiResponse)
        }
    })
}
}
```

This is I have in module

```
 @Module
public class AppCMSUIModule {


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Gson providesGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new Stag.Factory())
                .create();
        // return new Gson();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient providesOkHttpClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(defaultConnectionTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(defaultWriteConnectionTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(defaultReadConnectionTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Retrofit providesRetrofit(OkHttpClient client, Gson gson) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public PurchaseProductRest providesPurchaseProductRest(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(PurchaseProductRest.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public PurchaseProductCall providesPurchaseProductCall(PurchaseProductRest purchaseProductRest) {
        return new PurchaseProductCall(purchaseProductRest);
    }

}
```

Another module

```
@Module(includes = {AppCMSUIModule.class})
public class AppCMSPresenterModule {


@Provides
@Singleton
public AppCMSPresenter providesAppCMSPresenter(Gson gson,PurchaseProductCall purchaseProductCall){
    return new AppCMSPresenter(gson,purchaseProductCall);
}
```

}

When I build the app I get the error

```
 [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
```

Can someone guide me what is wrong here?

Comment: Where do you provide Retrofit?

Comment: Add code where you provide `PurchaseProductRest` adn `Retrofit` ..

Comment: @CôngHải it is in the same module

Comment: @ADM it is in the same module

Comment: how about Gson? maybe you should add full code of your Module

Comment: To address Circular  dependency go through all the modules that have been included in the component..

Comment: try to remove `providesPurchaseProductCall` method from module and add `@Singleton` to `class PurchaseProductCall`

Comment: @CôngHải updated the code